# dismiss ProgressDialog and show Toast from AsyncTask thread

Tags: android

This is the wireframe of how my class is built:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity 
{
    private ProgressDialog progressdialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    }       

    private class AuthenticateUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
    {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //do something  
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if (result.equals("success"))
                //do something
           else
           {               
               progressdialog.dismiss(); //this throws a null pointer exception
               /*
               When above line is commented to allow execution of app, Toast never shows on screen
               however no errors are recorded in the log
               */
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }
        }                   
    }   

    public void login(View v)
    {       
        progressdialog.show(HelloWorldActivity.this,"","Logging in...",true);
        new AuthenticateUserTask().execute();
    }   
}
```

I'm sorry if it seems I'm asking two questions in one thread, but I suspect the solution is similar for both.

Within onPostExecute:
 1. If login fails and I do `progressdialog.dismiss()`, a `null pointer exception` is thrown and application crashes.
2. If I remove the `ProgressDialog` and attempt to show a `Toast`, nothing show up on the screen, however no exception or error is recorded either.

**EDIT**
I found the solution to my first problem in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327369/how-can-i-dismiss-progressdialog-in-asynctask). 
I had to display the `ProgressDialog` in an `onPreExecute` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `ProgressDialog` to show, override the following method in your `AsyncTask`:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
  progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show( HelloWorldActivity.this, "", "Logging in..." );
}
```

**Note:** you need to remove this line from your `login()` method:

```
progressdialog.show(HelloWorldActivity.this,"","Logging in...",true);
```

The reason your `Toast` is not showing is that you forgot to call `.show()`:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have not initialized `progressDialog` object of `ProgressDialog`.

Correct way of doing this task :

1. In `onPreExecute()` of `AsyncTask` start `ProgressDialog`.
2. In `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` do your background stuff eg. connecting to webservice and get results or data.
3. In `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask` dismiss the `ProgressDialog` and then do the stuffs required.

Try using below code..

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity 
{
    private ProgressDialog progressdialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    }       

    private class AuthenticateUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
           progressDialog== ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "","Logging In....", true);
        }


        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //Login Functionality
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())                
                   progressdialog.dismiss(); 

            if (result.equals("success"))
                //do something
           else
           {   
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }                   
    }   

    public void login(View v)
    {       
        new AuthenticateUserTask().execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I scoped `progressdialog` within the AsyncTask though since I realized I don't ever need to call it from outside. I hadn't thought about using `onPreExecute` before.

Comment: Welcome.. You can get information about AsyncTask from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html